# How do I use `document.createElement()` to create an dismiss-able bootstrap alert?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, alert

How do I use `document.createElement()` to create an dismissable alert?

I am trying to add the below alert:

```
<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
  <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong> You should check in on some of those fields below.
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Using the `document.createElement()` function as seen in the code below:

```
document.createElement('

<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
  <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong> You should check in on some of those fields below.
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
</div>'

);
```

But keep getting the below error message: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`.

The browser console suggest that the error is in this line     `<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Document.createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?" - unfortunately, pretty much everything in the posted code is "wrong." Why are you trying to do it that way? Have you considered writing a simple utility function that takes a string of HTML and returns that constructed element and contents; for example: https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/x81fp0ua/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot use createElement like that.

##### Syntax

createElement(tagName)

createElement(tagName, options)

##### tagName

A string that specifies the type of element to be created. The nodeName of the created element is initialized with the value of tagName. Don't use qualified names (like "html:a") with this method. When called on an HTML document, createElement() converts tagName to lower case before creating the element. In Firefox, Opera, and Chrome, createElement(null) works like createElement("null").

please refer mdn documantation.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement

in this case, you can use DOMParser to parse the string to HTMLElement.

e.g.

```js
const parser = new DOMParser()

const dom = parser.parseFromString(`

<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
  <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong> You should check in on some of those fields below.
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
</div>`, 'text/html')

console.log(dom.body.firstChild)
```